# He hit on that thing

Tags: prepositional-phrases, direct-objects

You hit your head on a piece of a block. And can I reduce this sentence and tell someone simply, "he hit on that thing" or he hit on it?

Comment: Normally if you don't want to say what you hit your head on, you just say, "You hit your head."  If you want to interactively point out the thing, you can say,  "He hit his head on that [thing]."  But you've got to mention the head, otherwise just "hitting on something" is a completely different phrasal verb, that can either mean, "to happen upon as if by chance":  "He hit upon the solution after a couple hours of trying.:" OR "to make advances on someone for the purposes of sexual relations and/or dating.": "He was hitting on that girl until her brother hit him in the head with his backpack"

Comment: @Jim This would make a good answer.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't - in the intended context it doesn't make sense (another one, maybe...).

The shortened version would simply be:

> I/he hit my/his head.